# Scheme dice rolling algorithm

Tags: scheme

```
(define throw-3-die
  (cond
    [(+ 1 random)]
    [(+ random 3)]
    ))
```

The dice is six sided and are numbered 1-3 and have an equal probability of being rolled. I'm trying to figure out how to do this without an if statement or any arguments.

Comment: You don't need a `cond`, `if`, or any arguments, indeed. What do you understand of the code you've got? Before anybody here can help you, you have to be able to show what you do, and don't, already understand.

Comment: Here's a motivating question: how do you roll a _single_ die? If you can do this reliably, just repeat the process twice more and add up the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a skeletal solution:

```
(define (sum-of-three-dice)
  (define (one-die)
    <???>)
  (+ <???> <???> <???>))
```

It's really straightforward, if you think about it....

Comment: @user2785589 Of course! One of those `<???>` will indeed have `random` in it. It's up to you to figure out where.

Comment: how does (define (sum-of-three-dice)
            (define (one-die)
               random)
              (+ 1 2 3))
look?

Comment: @user2785589 Have you tried it? Does it give you the same result every time? Can't be very random now, can it? ;-)

Comment: the bottom 3 will be (+ random 1 3)

Comment: No. Let's try a different exercise. Write a `one-die` function that rolls one die and returns the result. That is, the result should be a random number between 1 and 6. Test it and make sure it works. Then paste me the code.